# Nav2 Collision Monitor: how to recover after stop

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, nav2, collision-detection

I use the Nav2 Collision Monitor as a kind of a (high level) security for my robot.

But after a stop the only way I found out is to send velocity commands direct to the robot.

So my question is there a recommended way to recover after a stop from Collision Monitor?
I think it should be possible e.g. to move backwards after recognizing an obstacle in front. Not all obstacle are dynamic and will move away after some time.

Thanks for any pointers

Michael

Answer (score 0):

Designing your keepout / slow down zones is definitely something worth putting some time into. Also note that we have `VelocityPolygons` so that you can gain schedule which polygons to use for what regimes of velocity commands and speeds.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the VelocityPolygons looks very interesting, but it seems that they are not available for Humble. Is it planned to port them?